# Using custom restClient in saga

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to select all locales from my API (api/locales).

My problem is that the yield call() return the function as a plan string (yes yes plain string) and I don't have a clue why!

Maybe I missed something with yield + call + restClient response?? =\

My Saga file look like this:

```
import types from './types';
import actions from './actions';
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import restClient from './../../restClient';

function* getLocalesSaga() {
  try {

    yield put({type: types.GET_LOCALES_LOADING});
    let locales;
    locales = yield call(restClient, 'GET', 'locales');
    console.log(locales); // this show the function string!!!
    if (!locales.data) {
      throw new Error('REST response must contain a data key');
    }
    yield put( {type: types.LOCALES_RECEIVED, locales } )

  } catch (error) {

    console.log(error);
    yield put({type: types.GET_LOCALES_FAILURE, error})

  }
}

export default function* localesSaga() {
  yield [
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES, getLocalesSaga),
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES_LOADING, actions.loadingLocales),
    takeEvery(types.LOCALES_RECEIVED, actions.localesReceived),
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES_FAILURE, actions.failedLocales),
  ];
}
```

The console.log output is:

```
ƒ (type, resource, params) {
    if (type === __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_admin_on_rest__["GET_MANY"]) {
      return Promise.all(params.ids.map(function (id) {
        return httpClient(apiUrl + '/' +…
```

There is no request in the browser networks tab.
No JS errors in console apart the console.log.

I registered the saga with customSagas={customsSagas} on the Admin component.

**When I use fetch() function it works!**

I want to use my restClient which include the authentication token and all logic of request and response.
The restClient is custom and this is the code:

```
import {
  GET_LIST,
  GET_ONE,
  GET_MANY,
  GET_MANY_REFERENCE,
  CREATE,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE,
  fetchUtils
} from 'admin-on-rest';

const { queryParameters, fetchJson } = fetchUtils;

const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH;

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
  }
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
  return fetchJson(url, options);
}
/**
 * Maps admin-on-rest queries to a json-server powered REST API
 *
 * @see https://github.com/typicode/json-server
 * @example
 * GET_LIST     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?_sort=title&_order=ASC&_start=0&_end=24
 * GET_ONE      => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * GET_MANY     => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123, GET http://my.api.url/posts/456, GET http://my.api.url/posts/789
 * UPDATE       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * CREATE       => POST http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * DELETE       => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
 */
export default () => {
  /**
   * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
   * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
   * @param {Object} params The REST request params, depending on the type
   * @returns {Object} { url, options } The HTTP request parameters
   */
  const convertRESTRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {
    let url = '';
    const options = {};
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
          ...params.filter,
          sort: field,
          order: order,
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
        };
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${queryParameters(query)}`;
        break;
      }
      case GET_ONE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        break;
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
          ...params.filter,
          [params.target]: params.id,
          _sort: field,
          _order: order,
          _start: (page - 1) * perPage,
          _end: page * perPage,
        };
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${queryParameters(query)}`;
        break;
      }
      case UPDATE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = 'PUT';
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      case CREATE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
        break;
      case DELETE:
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
        options.method = 'DELETE';
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported fetch action type ${type}`);
    }
    return { url, options };
  };

  /**
   * @param {Object} response HTTP response from fetch()
   * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
   * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
   * @param {Object} params The REST request params, depending on the type
   * @returns {Object} REST response
   */
  const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;
    switch (type) {
      case GET_LIST:
      case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
        if (!headers.has('x-total-count')) {
          throw new Error('The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer REST client expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?');
        }
        return {
          // change the primary key to uuid
          data: json.data.map(resource => resource = { ...resource, id: resource.uuid }),
          total: parseInt(headers.get('x-total-count').split('/').pop(), 10),
        };
      case UPDATE:
      case DELETE:
      case GET_ONE:
        return { data: json, id: json.uuid };
      case CREATE:
        return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.uuid } };
      default:
        return { data: json };
    }
  };

  /**
   * @param {string} type Request type, e.g GET_LIST
   * @param {string} resource Resource name, e.g. "posts"
   * @param {Object} payload Request parameters. Depends on the request type
   * @returns {Promise} the Promise for a REST response
   */
  return (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === GET_MANY) {
      return Promise.all(params.ids.map(id => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`)))
        .then(responses => ({ data: responses.map(response => response.json) }));
    }
    const { url, options } = convertRESTRequestToHTTP(type, resource, params);
    return httpClient(url, options)
      .then(response => convertHTTPResponseToREST(response, type, resource, params));
  };
};
```

Any one can help here and tell me why the restClient is returned as a string instead of returning the json?

It is not a GET_LIST nor GET_ONE request. It is just a normal GET request.
I tried to use GET_ONE and GET_LIST but I still get the response as the function plain string.

**Edit & Solution:**

Thanks to @Gildas it is clearer to use fetch instead of restClient for a GET request. restClient is used just for `<resource />` and it is not so clear by the docs.
Moreover, the actions creators were useless when I use `put` in my main saga function.

My fetch looks like this and it works:

```
function getLocales() {
  return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH + '/locales', { method: 'GET' })
      .then(response => (
          Promise.resolve(response)
      ))
      .then(response => (
          response.json()
      ))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
}
```

When I called it like this:

```
const { languages, currentLocale } = yield call(getLocales);
```

Thank you in advanced.
Leo.

Comment: I assume `actions.loadingLocales`, `actions.localesReceived` and `actions.failedLocales` are action creators ? Why are you using them as if they were sagas like `getLocalesSaga` ?

Comment: Hiii Gildas! thank you for the comment!  I'm using Ducks style: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be so I have actions and I'm using them in my operations.js file which includes all sagas... maybe I missed something and you can recommend on a better action creation methodology?

Comment: No, what I meant is that you're passing action creators as if they were sagas in the last 3 `takeEvery`. As far as I know, this could not work

Comment: Hi thanks again, the last 3 takeEvery work. The only thing that is not working is the restClient and over there is the issue. But you are right... there is no point for those actions if I `put` them in the main saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is really strange, it seems you're binding action creators as if they were sagas, though you do `put` them in the getLocalesSaga:

```
export default function* localesSaga() {
  yield [
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES, getLocalesSaga),
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES_LOADING, actions.loadingLocales),
    takeEvery(types.LOCALES_RECEIVED, actions.localesReceived),
    takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES_FAILURE, actions.failedLocales),
  ];
}
```

Moreover, the `restClient` is not `fetch`. `GET` is not a type recognized by it (see [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client)). You should not use the `restClient` for anything that's not a resource in admin-on-rest terms. Here, you should indeed use `fetch`.

This should probably be rewritten like:

```
import types from './types';
import actions from './actions';
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import restClient from './../../restClient';

function fetchLocales() {
    return fetch(...);
}

function* getLocalesSaga() {
  try {

    yield put(actions.loadingLocales());
    let locales;
    locales = yield call(fetchLocales);
    console.log(locales); // this show the function string!!!
    if (!locales.data) {
      throw new Error('REST response must contain a data key');
    }
    yield put(actions.localesReceived(locales))

  } catch (error) {

    console.log(error);
    yield put(actions.failedLocales(error))

  }
}

export default function* localesSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(types.GET_LOCALES, getLocalesSaga);
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! marked as correct and voted up!

Comment: Quick question, do you know how can I fire "getLocalesSaga" from the App.js file where I create the <Admin /> component? Now I load <Locales /> component and I fire the GET_LOCALES action creator on the componentWillMount function. Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to load the messages that you'll pass to the Admin component, that won't work. It will cause the Admin component to rerender with new props and you'll get redux errors about the store. Dynamic loading of messages is not supported right now. See the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Translation.html#changing-locale-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi Gildas, thank you for the doc link. I'm talking about dispatching the saga localesSaga>getLocalesSaga() when we load the Admin component. How can I dispatch an action on componentWillMount() of the Admin.

Comment: You can't dispatch actions in the component which is rendering the Admin component because the store won't be available yet. You'll have to build a custom app for that: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html. However, I think we should provide a way to load messages in aor, not just changing locales. I'll see what we can do about it

Comment: Maybe you can help here: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1279 I opened bug.